# Why does Lara Croft help the Illuminati find the pieces of the triangle of light?

Tags: plot-explanation, lara-croft-tomb-raider

So I just happened to watch the original Tomb Raider again and was not able to explain to myself why Lara Croft goes through the trouble of helping the Illuminati to carry out their mischievous deeds.

Her father tells her in his post-mortem letter to either not let the Illuminati have the clock, or to destroy it if need be. Why he didn't let her know of this obviously huge ordeal but a week before the whole thing goes down to the side, and assuming that his request is for her to destroy it for all time, rather than just not let them have it until the next 5000 years later total eclipse happens? Why does she simply not destroy the half of the triangle when she has it? At some point she literally hands it over to the bad guys! For about half the movie she is thereafter playing in cahoots with the people she is supposed to stop!

Is there something I'm missing in this thing? If she had destroyed the half (which is not so hard, bearing in mind she shot through it with a buncha "live rounds" at the end), then no matter in how many 5000 year intervals, the illuminati could have never brought it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of universe, the writers needed some way of driving the plot forward. In universe, after the Triangle was re-assembled, she and the Illuminati would cease co-operating, and she figured she would be able to somehow wrest control of it from them, use it to bring back her father, and then destroy it, denying the Illuminati their intended use. This solves the writers' problem, albeit by making the main character a co-conspirator with the villains, motivated by selfishness and arrogance.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I thought as well, but it seemed controversial for her to be so highly motivated in her whole life to follow in her father's footsteps and whenst confronted with an absolute letter of intent about what to do with this super important, super dangerous, world-ending power, she just goes and does her own thing. Also in terms of the writers - they never showed her as someone who is tempted by the power (a la Frodo in LOTR), she is the positive character all the way, which does not hold merit.